# XPath expression to select a node if attribute matches, or a node without this attribute otherwise

Tags: xml, xpath

Considering the following XML

```
<xml>
  <tag/>
  <tag version="2.1"/>
</xml>
```

I want an XPath 1.0 expression that returns `<tag version="2.1"/>` if I search for version 2.1, and `<tag/>` if I search for version 2.2.

So far, I've tried

```
/xml/tag[@version = '%version%' or not(@version)]
```

where `%version%` is a string that can be either 2.1 or 2.2, but if `%version%` is 2.1, it returns both nodes.

Comment: Searching on `2.1` returns both, because in your xpath you do `or not(@version)` and that will result in the tag without the attribute. So it does not matter what you pass into `%version%`, because always `<tag/>` will be returned because of the `or` statement... What you are trying to achieve is not possible in one XPath statement. Should be solved in code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this, using `|` (or)

```
    /xml[not(tag[@version="2.1"])]/tag[not(@version)] |
    /xml[tag[@version="2.1"]]/tag[@version="2.1"]
```

- either `xml` doesn't have `tag`s with `version="2.1"`, then return `tag`s with no `version` attribute
- or, if `xml` does contain `tag`s with `version="2.1"`, return these

So that would be in your case

```
    /xml[not(tag[@version='%version%'])]
        /tag[not(@version)]
    |
    /xml[tag[@version='%version%']]
        /tag[@version='%version%']
```

Answer (score 3):

As xpath 2.0 (if relevant) alternative to very nice @paul answer you could use

```
if (/xml/tag[@version = '2.1']) then /xml/tag[@version = '2.1'] else /xml/tag[not(@version)]
```

resp.

```
if (/xml/tag[@version = '%version%']) then /xml/tag[@version = '%version'] else /xml/tag[not(@version)]
```

Comment: That's indeed a very nice alternative, unfortunately I can't use xpath 2.0. I've updated my question accordingly.